# "half as fast" vs "twice as fast"

Tags: phrase-meaning, difference

Are these two meanings equivalent?

"half as fast" vs "twice as fast"

Ex:

Reaction A is **half** as fast as Reaction B.

Reaction A is **twice** as fast as Reaction B.

This is from my Chemistry textbook and I want to make sure I am interpreting it correctly.

Comment: Given that .5 is a different number than 2, it would be highly illogical for these two phrases to mean the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for your comment 3 years later

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no
the first sentence means : (the speed of reaction A) = (the speed of reaction B)/2
the second one means : (the speed of reaction A) = (the speed of reaction B) *2

Comment: "A is half as big as B" doesn't mean the same as "A is twice as big as B"!

Comment: "A is twice as small as B" is sometimes used to mean "A is half as big as B".